# Ruby Timeout Module - Timeout doesn't execute

Tags: ruby, exception, timeout

I came across the `Timeout` module in Ruby, and wanted to test it out. I looked at their official source code at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Here is the code I had

```
require 'timeout'
require 'benchmark'
numbers = [*1..80]
Timeout::timeout(5) { numbers.combination(5).count }

=> 24040016
```

I did some benchmarking tests, and got the following.

```
10.828000      0.063000     10.891000      11.001676
```

According to the documentation, this method is supposed to return an exception if the block is not executed within 5 seconds. If it is executed within the time frame, it will return the result of the code block

For what it's worth, I've tried timeout with 1 second, instead of 5 seconds, and I still get returned the result of the code block.

Here is the official documentation

```
timeout(sec, klass=nil)
Performs an operation in a block, raising an error if it takes longer than sec seconds to complete.

sec: Number of seconds to wait for the block to terminate. Any number may be used,
including Floats to specify fractional seconds. A value of 0 or nil will execute the
block without any timeout.

klass: Exception Class to raise if the block fails to terminate in sec seconds. Omitting
will use the default, Timeout::Error
```

I am mystified as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way MRI (Matz's Ruby Implementation) thread scheduling works. MRI uses a GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), which in practice means only one thread is truly running at a time.

There are some exception, but for the majority of the time there is only one thread executing Ruby code at any one time.

Normally you do not notice this, even during heavy computations that consume 100% CPU, because the MRI keeps time-slicing the threads at regular intervals so that each thread gets a turn to run.

However there's one exception where time-slicing isn't active and that's when a Ruby thread is executing native C-code instead of Ruby code.

Now it so happens that `Array#combination` is implemented in pure C:

```
[1] pry(main)> show-source Array#combination
From: array.c (C Method):

static VALUE
rb_ary_combination(VALUE ary, VALUE num)
{
  ...
}
```

When we combine this knowledge with how `Timeout.timeout` is implemented we can start to get a clue of what is happening:

```
[7] pry(main)> show-source Timeout#timeout
From: /opt/ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb @ line 75:

 75: def timeout(sec, klass = nil)   #:yield: +sec+
 76:   return yield(sec) if sec == nil or sec.zero?
 77:   message = "execution expired"
 78:   e = Error
 79:   bl = proc do |exception|
 80:     begin
 81:       x = Thread.current
 82:       y = Thread.start {
 83:         begin
 84:           sleep sec
 85:         rescue => e
 86:           x.raise e
 87:         else
 88:           x.raise exception, message
 89:         end
 90:       }
 91:       return yield(sec)
 92:     ensure
 93:       if y
 94:         y.kill
 95:         y.join # make sure y is dead.
 96:       end
 97:     end
 98:   end
 99:   ...
1xx: end
```

Your code running `Array.combination` most likely actually starts executing even BEFORE the timeout thread runs `sleep sec` on line 84. Your code is launched on line 91 through `yield(sec)`.

This means the order of execution actually becomes:

```
1: [thread 1] numbers.combination(5).count 
   # ...some time passes while the combinations are calculated ...
2: [thread 2] sleep 5 # <- The timeout thread starts running sleep
3: [thread 1] y.kill  # <- The timeout thread is instantly killed 
                      #    and never times out.
```

In order to make sure the timeout thread starts first you can try this, which will most likely trigger the timeout exception this time:

```
Timeout::timeout(5) { Thread.pass; numbers.combination(5).count }
```

This is because by running `Thread.pass` you allow the MRI scheduler to start and run the code on line 82 before the native `combination` C-code executes. However even in this case the exception won't be triggered until `combination` exits because of the GIL.

There is no way around this unfortunately. You would have to use something like JRuby instead, which has real concurrent threads. Or you could run the `combination` calculation in a `Process` instead of a thread.